# Web automation on different browsers via JScript in test complete tool displays browsers as Process(edge) instead of Browser(edge)

Tags: web, automation, testcomplete

Web Automation using Test complete tool.
Unable view browsers such as firefox, edge as Browser(edge), it is displayed as Process(edge).
Tried links provided in test complete documentation regarding preparing browsers for web automation, doesn't seem to work. If anyone has faced this kind of issue and got it resolved please help.

Test complete version 14.4.
Firefox version : 77
Edge version: 83.0.478.58

Comment: Hello, Sorry but I don't understand the question. Please edit it and explain first what you are trying to, then what your observe with your code (post the relevant part of it), so people can help you. For more info look to [mcve]. Best

Comment: Upon Launching different browsers such as chrome, Edge, Firefox, Test complete Tool object browser displays Browsers(Edge) or Browsers(Chrome) but currently for latest version of Edge it displays Process(Edge). I would like to know why is it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support a specific version of Firefox, you need to install the corresponding support modules. You can find these modules here:
https://support.smartbear.com/downloads/testcomplete/firefox-patches/

The "new" Edge based on Chromium isn't supported by TestComplete at the moment (2020-07-05), wait for an update from SmartBear. It should be released soon.

Comment: Any idea up to which version of Microsoft edge is supported by Test complete 14.4? ?

Comment: I am guessing that Edge version 44 should be supported.

Comment: That is true.. 44 is supported. But what about the later ones any idea?

Comment: Wait a couple of weeks for the next TestComplete release.